# How to find all connected edges from gas device feature using C# API call to ArcGIS Pro SDK?

Tags: c#, arcgis-pro, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am currently using connected trace to trace all the specified gas devices (using its Asset Group and Asset Type) to get output from the trace.

I want to find all the connected edge features from traced devices found in the trace output.

I am using ArcGIS Pro SDK to perform Utility Network-> Connected Trace to get the output as traced gas devices specified by a user (using its Asset Group and Asset Type).